# VS code module pygame has no init member

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I wanted to learn pygame so I downloaded it into VS code and began coding. As you know one of the first things you have to do is import pygame and after that pygame.init() when i did that there was an error saying pygame has no init member.The message pops up with some pygame functions such as pygame.quit(), but not with other ones such as pygame.time.Clock(). I looked online for answers and found some post that told me to add something to settings.json - when I did nothing had changed, I tried a couple of these but none of them seem to work. From what I understand, I should be able to run the code, it's just that the messages are annoying.

Comment: Do you have a module named pygame? The import will search the current directory for file names before searching the python library. After you call `import`, call `print(dir(pygame))`. This will list all the functions in the pygame module.

Comment: Yes, I had installed it with pip3. When I call print it prints all of the functions pygame has, including the ones that are underlined as not existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used the module "`pygame`", I reproduced the problem you described:

(Although the code can be executed, there is an error "no init member")

[image]

**Solution:**

Please add

> ```
> "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
>     "----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml",
>    
>   ],
> ```

in "`settings.json`", and use the latest version of VScode.( **Version: 1.50.1** )

result:

[image]